# Problem "do shell script" on curl – Works in Terminal, but not via "do shell script"

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I want to use "curl" with "do shell script" in an apple script. It already worked some months ago, but then the provider changed to https-only service.

So I update curl on Mac OS Terminal:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.49.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0) libcurl/7.49.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2h zlib/1.2.8
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

So it works in Terminal and gives back the right answer:
[image]

But when I try to call the same command via do shell script in Apple Script it responds this:
[image]

So – is the problem, that curl in the do shell script environment isn't updated - and how could I do this? Or what is the problem?

Comment: How did you update curl?

Comment: I updated it with homebrew.

Comment: You did not update it you added another curl in a different place and applescript does not have to on its path

Comment: The `do shell script` command gets passed `"/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"` as the `$PATH` and therefore any commands called that are not within that _path_ need to use the fully qualified pathname in the command. This also applies to commands called in Automator when using Run Shell Script and Run AppleScript actions too.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the solution. The problem is, that homebrew installed an optional newer version of curl, but the command `do shell script` does use the old version.

After a hint from a friend I used `which curl` in terminal and apple script editor and get different results:

Terminal says: /opt/local/bin/curl 
Apple Script `do shell script` says: /usr/bin/curl

So the solution for my problem is to force do shell sript to use the newer version via:

`do shell script "/opt/local/bin/curl \"https://v.gd/create.php?format=simple&url=http://www.test.de\""`

Comment: two things wrong - it is not an optional version it is just another version. Home-brew does not put things in /opt/local - Macports does that. The general issue of using the full path os correct